# Migración de una BD de excel a Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, migration, migracion

Se está migrando una BD de Excel para Access(2007-2016) con el propósito de mejorar los procesos de almacenamiento y rendimiento de la consulta de la información.

Inicialmente hay una tabla que contiene 23 mil registros que guardan el detalle de los gastos donde la columna **RADICADO DE GASTOS** es el número de documento que se le asigna al reporte de los gastos que reportan los empleados y el # de radicado es único por reporte, pero se repite en la BD porque se guarda la información dependiendo de las siguientes columnas:**FECHA REAL DE GASTOS** ,**DESCRIPCIÓN** y **RADICADO DE GASTOS** y están de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se realizo una partición de la tabla en tres tablas pequeñas que se agruparan las columnas por conceptos en ACCESS de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde ID es un contador de registros, se intenta hacer una relación entre las tres tablas para poder llamar todos los registros y poder llegar a mostrar una consulta con la estructura de la tabla de Excel (BD_GASTOS).

Intentando crear la llave que nos permita relacionar las tablas se buscó crear una nueva columna llamada **LLAVE** que concatena la columna **DOCUMENTO** Y **RADICADO DE GASTOS** en las tres tablas pero cuando ejecuto la siguiente sentencia no se crean las llaves:

```
UPDATE DESCRIPCION GASTOS SET LLAVE = [DOCUMENTO] & "-" & [RADICADO DE GASTOS];
```

Se intento hacerlo sin la llave solo llamando el documento utilizando el siguiente código:

```
SELECT *FROM REGISTROS DE EMPLEADOS TR1 JOIN GASTOS TR3 ON TR1.DOCUMENTO= TR3.DOCUMENTO LEFT JOIN DESCRIPCION GASTOS TR2 ON TR1.DOCUMENTO = TR2.DOCUMENTO ON TR2.DOCUMENTO= TR3.DOCUMENTO;
```

Agradezco si pueden darme soporte respecto a la partición de la tabla y en que parte estoy fallando además de cualquier consejo o buenas prácticas para este tipo de casos.

Comment: si DESCRIPCION GASTOS es el nombre de la tabla, que es una mala idea que lo sea por el espacio, entonces deberia ir entre corchetes para que funcione. De paso, Excel no es una base de datos, nunca lo fue, nunca lo sera, es una planilla de calculos.

Comment: En un par de años vamos a escuchar que necesitan migrar de Access a SQLServer. Por qué no utilizan SQL Server Express de una vez? O es esto una tarea de la uni?

Comment: Eliminaré los espacios, gracias. Y respecto a lo por qué no utilizo SQLServer es porque la empresa quiere almacenar la información en ACCESS por la familiaridad que tiene con el Excel además de la facilidad de crear formularios para la captación de datos. Este proceso es de una empresa que recién está haciendo una actualización tecnológica por ende tiene malas prácticas.

Comment: @Arriel No sean elitistas con las herramientas. VBA es código y esos archivos de excel son una base de datos. No es relacional, no está normalizada, pero es _la base de datos_ del usuario. Que está trabajando con lo que tiene a la mano. No juzguen al OP y respondan a la pregunta. Si fuese un científico de datos con su _base de datos_, nadie lo estaría juzgando.

Comment: Hola! Sí, procura no usar espacios en nombres de cosas; suele ser problemático cuando intentas mencionar esas cosas más adelante. Mismo ejercicio con tildes y carácteres especiales, trata de ser tan ASCII como sea posible.  Si al ajustar ves que funciona diferente, puedes [edit] la pregunta para ver en que sigue sin funcionar o revisar con @gbianchi si publican la solución como respuesta :)

Comment: @Alfabravo, no veo el elitismo. Excel es una base de datos en la misma manera que un archivo de notepad puede serlo, cuál es tu punto? Tal vez es la mala costumbre de ser consultor, vemos problemas en el camino y anticipamos. Si fuese un científico de datos y alguien tuviese una crítica, se critica. No hay que pensarse absoluto, nadie está exento de ser criticado. Si coincido contigo cuando dices *VBA es código* pero, nuevamente, fallo en ver tu punto. Lo lamento.

Comment: @Arriel que no usen la herramienta que tú prefieres no significa que sea _la tarea de la uni_. Si eres consultor, seguro te has topado con numerosos escenarios donde los usuarios resuelven con lo que tienen a la mano y con lo que saben hacer. Es decir, MS Office. Y sí, los consultores tienen la mala costumbre, como muchos ingenieros (colegas míos) de hacer soluciones overkill por usar lo más moderno, más estable, etc... En fin. COmentarios fuera de lugar a la pregunta que no planeo extender.

Comment: @Alfabravo la pregunta dice (y cito) "Se está migrando una BD de Excel" y no.. Que se use como base de datos, no quiere decir que sea una base de datos... entonces, le corregi a OP ese detalle, pero nada mas.. todo se puede usar como db, pero nosotros, con el conocimiento, debemos detallar esas cosas, para no generar confusion.  En mi caso yo no le recomende nada mas, porque no hago soluciones sin saber los porque... salvo que sea algo mas obvio.. si la empresa se arreglaba con un excel de 20000 filas, cualquier cosa es mucho...

Comment: @HugoBermudez ya que os estáis mudando a Access (una bbdd relacional) aprovechad ahora para definir bien las relaciones, ya que te evitarás muchos dolores de cabeza en el futuro. Lo primero que debes hacer es dividir tus datos en objetos y ver qué propiedades necesitas en cada uno. Eso te permitirá saber cuántas tablas vas a necesitar (yo intuyo que 4, pero no estoy seguro 100%). Por lo que veo en tus imágenes diría que tienes 3 objetos: *Empleado*, *Gasto* y *Descripción Gasto*. Antes de ponerte a crear tablas e intentar actualizar, estudia las relaciones. Por ejemplo (sigo abajo)

Comment: ¿Podría un *Gasto* estar asociado a más de una  *Descripción Gasto*? ¿Y viceversa? Tienes que ver todas las relaciones entre todos tus objetos. Como dije antes, intuyo que necesitas 4 tablas: tres para cada uno de tus objetos y una cuarta que será donde piques lo que teníais en el Excel. No tendrás que picar todo, posiblemente con relacionar solamente id's de cada objeto será suficiente.  Por otro lado, en relación a tu consulta SQL, es **muy recomendable** que todas las tablas/campos y demás se llamen con una sola palabra y sin símbolos rarunos (asteriscos, arrobas y cosas así).